# How to pass Payment Intent Id in Checkout in Stripe?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, checkout

I am trying stripe in test mode in Django. I am new here.
I want to let customer **choose the card from their saved cards for checkout**. I am storing customer's preferred card (payment method which is pm_xxxxxxx) in selected_card_id. Then I have created Payment Intent. Now I want to pass this payment intent id into checkout.

But currently my code is creating **two payment intents**:
(1.) in payment intent which stays **INCOMPLETE** ue to 3DS authentication (and I can't do anything about it as it is in test mode)
(2.) in checkout which is getting **COMPLETED** but it is using only the **last saved card**.

Here is my code:

```
        # For getting id of current logged in user
        current_user_id = request.user.id
        user = User.objects.get(id = current_user_id) 
        selected_card_id = request.session.get("selected_card_id")
        
        # Create customer id for new user
        if not user.customer_id:
            customer = stripe.Customer.create()
            user.customer_id = customer.id
            user.save()
       
        payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            currency='inr',
            customer = user.customer_id,
            amount=299900,  # Amount in paise
            payment_method=selected_card_id,
            confirm = True,
        )

        payment_intent_id = payment_intent["id"]

        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            mode='payment',
            payment_intent= payment_intent_id,
            payment_method_types=['card'],                
            line_items=[
                {
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'price': 'price_1NevYPSIWq54gkyCEytMLqZ1',
                }
            ],
            success_url=domain_url + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancelled/',
            customer=user.customer_id
        )
```

My objective can be achieved either if Payment Intent can be completed without 3DS Authentication or if I can pass payment intent id in checkout.

**Help is much appreciated. Thank you. **

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a PaymentIntent when creating a Checkout Session. However you can pass [PaymentIntent's data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data) into your Checkout Session, that will be filled in the resulting PaymentIntent of the Checkout Session.

You an find [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) all the supported paramter. In your code you should remove the separate PaymentIntent creation and keep only the Checkout Session creation.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer. But how can I make sure that customer can choose a card for checkout. I have made a separate page where customer can choose a card and I save the payment id of that card in SELECTED_CARD_ID. How can I pass it in checkout, as I have tried checkout doesn't take payment_method.

Comment: You can't pass (existing) PaymentMethod to a Checkout Session.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is create and confirm a Payment Intent for a saved payment method that won't require additional actions.
You can do this by indicating that the payment is off session (even if the customer is technically present, setting the payment as off-session will exempt it from authentication).

Checkout can't do this - it is designed to collect payment details on session.

What you actually want is to create and confirm a Payment Intent with the `off_session=True` flag, which is documented here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method

Now, one elephant in the room here is the 'INR' currency I'm seeing. If your account is affected by RBI regulations, then there is a ton more requirements you need to take into account for implementing this logic:
https://stripe.com/docs/india-recurring-payments?integration=paymentIntents-setupIntents